# Display only taxonomy parents from an entity reference field

Tags: taxonomy-terms

Is there a taxonomy entity reference field formatter to display only taxonomy parents from hierarcherical taxonomy elements ?
Else what could be the way to display, from an entity reference field, only the taxonomy terms parents?

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom view mode for taxonomy terms and display the taxonomy term as "rendered entity", using your customized view mode.

Then create a Twig template for that special view mode: Assuming your newly created view mode is `onlyparents`, create a template `taxonomy-term--onlyparents.html.twig`

There is no field like "parents", so there also is no pre-built field formatter for this. To get the parents, you will need to do some manual preprocessing like

```
function mymodule_preprocess_taxonomy_term(&$variables) {
  $term = $variables['elements'];
  $parents = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
    ->getStorage('taxonomy_term')
    ->loadAllParents($term->id());
  $variables['parents'] = $parents;
}
```

In Twig you can do something like

```
{% for parent in parents %}
  {{ parent.label }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: i do not get it , a custom view mode ?

Comment: I think it is "view_mode" in code and "display mode" in the english UI: `/admin/structure/display-modes/view`. Just like nodes have a full view mode and a teaser view mode

Comment: got it now but how to make that display mode displaying only the term parents?

Comment: I've added some code examples, but I'm writing that untested, by memory. Feel free to edit my answer if you find some errors.

Comment: $term is an array . i cannot figure out how to get the tid from the $variables

Answer (score 0):

Inspired from Hudri answer, i have :

- created a taxonomy display mode taxo_parent_only
- use that display mode for my node entity referenced field display
- Add a suggestion and preprocess to my .theme
- Add a specific template

  ```
   function my_theme_theme_suggestions_taxonomy_term_alter(&$suggestions,
   $vars, $hook) { 
      $term = $vars['elements']['#taxonomy_term'];  
      $sanitized_view_mode = strtr($vars['elements']['#view_mode'], '.',
    '_');  
     $suggestions[] = 'taxonomy_term__' . $term->bundle() . '__' .
     $sanitized_view_mode;   $suggestions[] = 'taxonomy_term__' .
      $term->id() . '__' . $sanitized_view_mode;   $suggestions[] =
      'taxonomy_term__' . $sanitized_view_mode;

      return $suggestions; }


   function my_theme_doc_preprocess_taxonomy_term(&$variables) {   
       /* test if term is rank 1 of tree */   
     $term = $variables['elements']['#taxonomy_term'];
     $storage = \Drupal::service('entity_type.manager')
    ->getStorage('taxonomy_term');
  $parents = $storage->loadParents($term->id());          
  if(count($parents)===0){
       $variables['is_taxo_parent']= TRUE;   }
   }
  ```

taxonomy-term--myvocab--taxo-parent-only.html.twig

```
{% if is_taxo_parent is defined %}
    <div{{ attributes }}>
      {{ title_prefix }}
      {% if name and not page %}
        <a href="{{ url }}">{{ name }}</a>
      {% endif %}
      {{ title_suffix }}
      {{ content }}
    </div>
{% endif %}
```